# How can I sum an interval of elements on an array in python / numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, numpy, sum

How can I sum an interval of elements on an array in python / numpy ?

For example, in matlab it is possible something like this:

```
y= ones(10,20);
y(1:5,:) = 2;
for k = 1: 10
   psum(k) = sum(y((1:3),k));
end
```

But sum function from numpy doesn't suport "1:3"

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably something like this:

```
y = numpy.ones((10, 20))
y[0:5] = 2
psum = y[0:3].sum(axis=0)
```

A simpler example:

```
y = numpy.array([2, 6, 7, 3, 4])
print y[1:4].sum()
```

prints `16`, the sum of the middle three elements.

Comment: Not exactly; the Matlab program returns all sixes (at least in Octave).

Comment: @larsmans: Then something about the order of the indices in Matlab and NumPy is different.  I added a simpler example to make clear how to sum over an array slice.

Comment: @Bago: I figured that out, but I messed it up in a different way, unrelated to differences between Matlab and NumPy.  Should be essentially fixed now.

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```
>>> y = np.ones((10, 20))
>>> y[0:5, :] = 2
>>> psum = y[0:3, 0:10].sum(axis=0)
```

Note that in Python, indices are zero-based and end indices are non-inclusive.